# UITabbarController UITabbarItem does not appear when UINavigationController is embeded

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

As the title says, does the UITabbarItem not appear if I embed in a UINavigationController like so:

```
lazy var tabBarViewController: UITabBarController = {
        let tBarViewController = UITabBarController()

        let firstViewController = ViewController()
        firstViewController.tabBarItem.title =  "Home"
        tBarViewController.viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)]

        return tBarViewController
        }()

    lazy var window: UIWindow = {
        let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        win.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        win.rootViewController =  self.tabBarViewController
        return win
        }()


    func customizeAppereance() {

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.themeColor()
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor =  UIColor.themeColor()

    }


    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

        customizeAppereance()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .Fade)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

[image]

If I remove the UINavigationController it works and the UITabbarItem is visible. 
How can I embed in a UINavigationController and have the UITabbarItem to appear? (I am not using NIBs or Storyboard, just code) ?

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar item has to belong to the view controller you're adding to the tab bar controller - in this case, the navigation controller. Otherwise, it tries to create one from the title (non-existent).

You need to set the tabBarItem property on the navigation controller, not its root view controller.